# AWS ECS scale up and down ways

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

We are using AWS  ECS service where docker containers are running into it. These docker container having application code which continuously polling SQS and gets the single message, process it and kill their self and that's the life cycle of task. 
Now we are scaling tasks and EC2 in cluster based on number of messages comes to SQS. We are able to scale up but it's difficult to scale down because we don't know whether any task is still processing any message because message processing time is huge due to some complex logic.
Could anybody suggest what's the based way to scale up and scale down in this case?

Comment: The problem you describe seems to be a pretty good use case for using AWS Batch with multinode deployment. You may want to take a look at that service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using AWS Lambda for this use case rather than ECS (provided that your application logic runs in less than 5 mins). You can use SQS as a trigger for the Lambda. [AWS Documentation : Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) provides a comprehensive guide on how to achieve this using Lambda.

Comment: my task execution time could go beyond hour or more, hence lambda does not fit.

Answer (score 0):

The use case you have mentioned doesn't mean for ECS for EC2 instances. You should consider AWS ECS Fargate or AWS BATCH. On one side fargate will give you more capabilities in term of infrastructure like The task can be run for longer periods or scaling of tasks according to some parameters like CPU or MEM. On another side, you will be paying only the number of tasks running at a moment in your cluster.

Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/